# Как распарсить JSON с помощью GSON на android

Tags: java, json, gson

```
{
    "company": {
        "name":"High Technologies Center",
        "age": "15",
        "competences": ["Android", "IOS", ".NET", "PHP", "Smart-TV"],
        "employees": [{
            "name": "John",
            "phone_number": "769453",
            "skills": ["Java", "Android"]
        }, {
            "name": "Diego",
            "phone_number": "987924",
            "skills": ["Java", "Smart-TV"]
        }, {
            "name": "Alfred",
            "phone_number": "452533",
            "skills": ["Objective-C", "Android", "Photoshop"]
        }, {
            "name": "John",
            "phone_number": "212456",
            "skills": ["Java", "Phython"]
        }, {
            "name": "Mat",
            "phone_number": "778975",
            "skills": ["Android", "MovieMaker"]
        }, {
            "name": "Bob",
            "phone_number": "456468",
            "skills": ["Groovy", "Kotlin"]
        }, {
            "name": "Marty",
            "phone_number": "321789",
            "skills": ["Android", "PHP", "C#"]
        }]  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1.Загоняете ваш JSON в http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ и получаете Java классы, которые  вы потом импортируете в ваш проект.
2.Получаете объект с помощью команды

```
Gson gson = new Gson();    
Entity read = gson.fromJson(json, Entity.class);
```

Подробности: http://www.javenue.info/post/gson-json-api

Comment: Укажите точнее куда их импортировать. И что Entity вы использовали?

Comment: Entity - Это класс, который был загенерен при помощи http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Comment: В проекте создайте пакет для ваших сущностей. При генерации на сайте есть поле Package, в него введите имя вашего пакета. После генерации поместит .java файлы в этот пакет в проекте.